# Cubic polynomial of Neuberg Cubic

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-geometry

It's certain that:for given $\triangle ABC$, the Neuberg cubic can be drawn. I know the trilinear equation and barycentric equation of it, but I can find any information about its polynomial representation, like
$$
c_1x^3+c_2y^3+c_3x^2y+c_4xy^2+c_5x^2+c_6y^2+c_7xy+c_8x+c_9y+c_{10}=0.
$$
If $A(a_1,a_2),B(b_1,b_2),C(k_1,k_2)$(in cartesian coordinates), can anyone help me express that 10 coefficients using $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,k_1,k_2$?

---

My purpose is to draw the Neuberg curve in pgf\tikz, and they require the polynomial.

Comment: The Neuberg cubic *really* likes homogeneous coordinates, so Cartesian form is a mess. Perhaps the best way to proceed is to take the barycentric form you know (say, in $u:v:w$ coordinates) and substitute a barycentric form of $(x,y)$:
$$u = \left|\begin{matrix} x&b_1&k_1\\ y&b_2&k_2\\ 1&1&1 \end{matrix}\right|\quad
v = \left|\begin{matrix} x&k_1&a_1\\ y&k_2&a_2\\ 1&1&1 \end{matrix}\right|\quad
w = \left|\begin{matrix} x&a_1&b_1\\ y&a_2&b_2\\ 1&1&1 \end{matrix}\right|$$

Comment: @Blue see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neuberg's 1884 paper introducing the cubic defined it as those points satisfying the determinant equation
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&(BC)+(PA)&(BC)(PA)\\
1&(CA)+(PB)&(CA)(PB)\\
1&(AB)+(PC)&(AB)(PC)\end{vmatrix}=0$$
where $(XY)=(X-Y)\cdot(X-Y)$ is the squared distance between $X$ and $Y$, a quadratic polynomial in point coordinates. Expanding the determinant in point coordinates yields a messy expression that is nevertheless cubic in $x$ and $y$.

Fixing $A=(-1,0)$, $B=(1,0)$ and $C=(p,q)$ gives the simpler expression
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\y\\y^2\\y^3\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}3p(p^2+q^2-1)&-3p^2-q^2+3&-3p(p^2+q^2-1)&3p^2+q^2-3\\
-6pq&-2q(p^2+q^2-3)&2pq\\
-p(p^2+q^2-1)&3p^2+q^2-3\\
2pq\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\x\\x^2\\x^3\end{bmatrix}=0$$

Comment: Do you know how I can draw it in latex?

Comment: @SetnessRamesory That, please go to https://tex.stackexchange.com.